# Recording audio streaming in android without microphone

Tags: android, audio, stream, microphone

I'm trying to create app that stream radio from internet im using MediaPlayer  class for that and its working fine.

i want to add recording function to the app and i use MediaRecorder class for that with this seting

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

but i it catch the microphone sound. i want to record the stream sound only.

what i can do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to record the audio playback like that.
It *is* possible to get audio data from your `MediaPlayer` by using the [`Visualizer` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html), but that audio will be of *very* low quality since it's intended only for visualizing purposes, so I doubt that it will be good enough for your needs.

Another alternative would be to handle the streaming in a sort of proxy/relay server running within your app, which could then take the audio data it gets from the remote server and write it to a file as well as to your `MediaPlayer`.